# traversing parents and setting property conditionally

Tags: c#

I have an class:

```
class Unit
{
    string Name;
    Unit Parent;       
    bool IsInCharge;
    Unit ParentUnitThatIsInCharge;
}
```

I want to traverse the parents to find the Parent that is in charge and set it to ParentUnitThatIsInCharge.

I have the function that gets the ParentUnitThatIsInCharge:

```
public Unit GetParentUnitThatIsInCharge(Unit unit)
{
    Unit inChargeUnit= null;

    if (unit.Parent != null)
    {
        do
        {
            inChargeUnit= unit.Parent;
        } while (!inChargeUnit.IsInCharge);
    }
    return inChargeUnit;
}
```

I want to set the class property to the result of the function.  How would I go about doing this when the object is set?

Comment: What do you mean by "class property"?  Properties belong to each instance of a class (they are non-static).

Comment: Your question (And code..) are a bit unclear... can you provide a data sample? (Input + requested output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParentUnitThatIsInCharge` is a derived value.  It is dependent on the other values set in the object.  You can re-calucluate that derived value anytime someone asks for it:

```
    public class Unit
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Unit Parent { get; set; }
        public bool IsInCharge { get; set; }
        public Unit ParentUnitThatIsInCharge
        {
            get
            {
                return GetParentUnitThatIsInCharge(this);
            }
        }

        public static Unit GetParentUnitThatIsInCharge(Unit unit)
        {
            Unit current = unit;
            while (!current.IsInCharge && current.Parent != null)
            {
                current = current.Parent;
            }
            return current;
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you can make the values that it is dependent on be properties (which you should really do regardless, when exposing them publicly) and have them re-compute the derived value when they're set, but the problem there is the `ParentThat IsInCharge` property can change not only when this unit's properties change, but when any of the parent's properties change, and there's no real good way (given the API provided) to know when any of your parent's properties have changed.  You'd have to give `Unit` an event that fires when any of the properties change, and then when any of them fire re-compute the value (and even attach/unattach event handlers as the unit ancestors could have changed).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to set the property for the given instance, you don't need to return a value at all (although you certainly can...).
Simply do:

```
public Unit GetParentUnitThatIsInCharge(Unit unit)
{
    Unit inChargeUnit= null;

    if (unit.Parent != null)
    {
        do
        {
            inChargeUnit= unit.Parent;
        } while (!inChargeUnit.IsInCharge);
    }

    unit.ParentUnitThatIsInCharge = inChargeUnit;
    return inChargeUnit;
}
```

Comment: And the -1 is for... ?